# How to define an onclick function on Laravel Collectives?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have implemented a drop down using Laravel collectives. I need to call `function setMaterialValue(let x){ console.log(x)}` on each time I select a material. This should be specific to each material as cotton-10, wetlook-20, crocodile-30 etc. Without Laravel collective this can be performed as

```
<option onclick="setMaterialValue(10);">Cotton</option>
```

How to perform this using Laravel collectives?

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header"><h2 class="card-title m-0">Feature Selector</h2></div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <h5 class="card-title"><b>Material Selector</b></h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Textile Material
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{Form::select('material_selector', [
                        '10' => 'Cotton', 
                        '20' => 'Wet Look',
                        '30' => 'Crocodile',
                    ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Select Material'],['class'=>'form-control'])
                }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI - Where your class declaration is add it and any other html attributes there as well:

```php
{{  Form::select('material_selector', 
    [
        '1' => 'Cotton', 
        '2' => 'Wet Look',
        '3' => 'Crocodile',
    ], 
    null, 
    ['placeholder' => 'Select Material'],
    [
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'onclick'=>'setMaterialValue(10)' // <== ADD IT HERE
    ])
}}
```

Comment: 'onclick'=>'setMaterialValue(10)' this will send 10  each time I select a value from the drop down menu. Actually what i need is to send 10 when only cotton is selected. If wetlook is selected then it must be 20

Comment: Can't you just pass `['cotton-10' => 'Cotton', 'wet-look-20' => 'Wet Look','crocodile-30' => 'Crocodile',]`? If not, I think I have another solution but it will get gross for sure, so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use jQuery. Then you can address your select element as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control[name="material_selector"]').on('change', showSelectedValue);
  
  function showSelectedValue(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    console.log(target.val() + " = " + target.find('option:selected').text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material_selector" class="form-control">
  <option value="10">Cotton</option>
  <option value="20">Wet Look</option>
  <option value="30">Crocodile</option>
</select>
```

**Another option**

If you really do not want to use jQuery, then try to use the `onChange` attribute for the `select` tag like the example below

```php
{{Form::select(
    'material_selector', // name attribute of the select
    ['10' => 'Cotton', '20' => 'Wet Look', '30' => 'Crocodile'], // option values
    null, // selected value, for example '20'
    ['placeholder' => 'Select Material', 'class' => 'form-control', 'onChange' => 'showSelectedValue(this)'], // attributes for <select>
)}}
```

```js
 function showSelectedValue(element) {
  console.log(element.value + " = " + element.options[element.selectedIndex].text);
 }
```

```html
<select name="material_selector" class="form-control" onChange="showSelectedValue(this)">
  <option value="10">Cotton</option>
  <option value="20">Wet Look</option>
  <option value="30">Crocodile</option>
</select>
```